# How do I find & replace a character between a text in 2 tags?

Tags: html, xml, replace, words

usually I find all the answers to my questions on this forum, but now I really can't figure out what to do.

I get a .xml file from a program and we use this xml file to create an article/product on our website.
The output from the program is like this:

```
<BigInfo>Description English: Spring washer&lt;br&gt;Descrizione Italiano: Rosetta</BigInfo>
```

and I want to have the output like this:

```
<BigInfo><![CDATA[Description English: Spring washer<br>Descrizione Italiano: Rosetta]]></BigInfo>
```

I allready wrote a script that replaces
`<BigInfo>` for `<BigInfo><![CDATA[` and `</BigInfo>` for `]]></BigInfo>`

but now I need to replace the `&lt;`and `&gt;` for `<` between the BigInfo tags.

I hope you all can help me with this!

Kind regards,

Koen de Haan

Comment: From XML point of view, the two formats are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

What is your script language? PHP has for example:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

which does exactly what you want:

```
<?php
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

$a = htmlentities($orig);

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
?>
```

Comment: A sorry, I used a script made with powershell to put the CDATA in my .xml file.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.100).aspx this is a powershell option

Comment: Thanks a lot! this will help me out!